# Cannot load Stack Overflow on my system

Tags: support, stack-overflow, 500-server-error, dns

When I request Stack Overflow from my home system, my system shows the following error:

> **Oops! This page appears broken. DNS Error — Server cannot be found.**

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If DNS is that horribly borked, you can override. For example, on windows edit `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add:

```
69.59.196.211   stackoverflow.com
```

then clear your DNS (`ipconfig /flushdns`) and you should be in business.

But easier: wait for DNS to fix itself ;p

Comment: You don't need to clear the DNS after modifying the hosts file. Anyways this will only partly work, you would have to add all domains used by stackoverflow this way